# What is the integral of temperature over space called?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, terminology

Consider the heat equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=k\cdot\Delta u$ where $u\colon\Omega\times \mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}$ maps the space variable $x\in \Omega$ and a time variable $t$ to a temperature.

Is there a name for the quantity
$$h_t = \int_\Omega u(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x \quad? $$

I was under the impression that this quantity is called heat, but the Wikipedia article for heat disagrees. What should this be called?

Answer (score 3):

By integrating the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Statement_of_the_equation)
$$\rho c \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} - \nabla \cdot \left( k \nabla T \right) = \dot q$$
over a volume $\Omega$, assuming no heat flux through the boundary $\delta\Omega$, you find that
$$\int_\Omega 
\rho c Tdx=Q,$$
so the heat $Q=\int_\Omega qdx$ equals the spatial integral of the product of temperature $T$, mass density $\rho$, and specific heat capacity $c$. For uniform $\rho$, $c$ you would simply have $\int_\Omega Tdx=Q/\rho c$.

Comment: Are $\rho$ and $c$ possibly functions of location $x$? Taking them outside of the integral like that seems fine if they are constant throughout space, otherwise I don't get it.

Comment: certainly, if these material constants are spatially dependent they should stay inside the integral --- thanks for noting this.

Comment: The left hand side of this equation $\int_\Omega 
\rho c Tdx=Q$ is called the *internal energy* of the material.